# What does npm i react-{...} do?

Tags: npm, installation, package-managers

I saw this at a tutorial, what does that syntax mean? Install both `react-router` and `react-redux`?

`npm i react-{router,redux}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will install both react-router and react-redux. It works the same as:

```
npm install react-router react-redux
```